# Can Juggernauts kill each other with friendly fire in CoD: Modern Warfare 2 Special Ops mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2 Special Ops, could Juggernauts kill each other with friendly fire? In particular, in Estate Takedown?

I'm playing on PS3 (if this matters).

Comment: Could any enemy? I can't remember any enemy dying from friendly fire...

Answer (score 1):

Without experimentation, I'd have to say that this is possible (from the point of view of game mechanics) but unlikely.

According to the [Call of Duty Wikia pages](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Plot_armor):

> Characters without plot armor (such as randomly generated soldiers) can die from any fatal event, including accidental death at the hands of the player.

I've observed this in-game myself, although not in this specific case. I'd imagine that because Juggernauts can soak up a lot of damage, and the enemy AI has routines in place to tell it to get out of the way of gunfire, it would take a very contrived situation to allow this to happen.